# line 3 divs on one line

Tags: html, css, html-email, mailchimp

I am trying to get a [mailchimp](/questions/tagged/mailchimp) signup form to be on the same line instead of the default 3 lines.

I have tried to add display: inline-block; which made no difference and I have also tried to put a container around the divs but that didn't make a difference.

I do not have much experience of css but I do understand it.  I was wondering if someone with a little more experience may be able to help.

```
    <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//digital-realms.us12.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=b3dcff09f16684d5f73852c78&amp;id=af1750ad39" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

<div>Sign up to free e-Mail alerts for the latest news, offers & more: </div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_b3dcff09f16684d5f73852c78_af1750ad39" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear opt-in" "><input type="submit" value="Sign Up" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Thank you.

ps: The code came from MailChimp and they set the classes so I do not have any css of my own to include.

Comment: While using `inline-block`, have you tried to change the width of the divs ?

Comment: @Jewel, that worked brilliantly.  The 30% didn't work but by placing values instead of the percentages i got it to work like a dream.

Comment: I have to also use [at]media so when the website is used on a mobile device, but that is OK (I think we all expect mobile sites to look different to desktop ones).

@Heru-Luin,  When I was using line-block; I think I had widths set as % in their divs but I do prefer the answer Jewel gave because i understand it easier (if that makes sense).

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following html

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
}
.block1 {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.block2 {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.block3 {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="block1">Content 1</div>
  <div class="block2">Content 2</div>
  <div class="block3">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

You may change the width. and insert your html into the content 1, content 2, content 3